# Long type output file

Tags: java, file

I tried to create a file and write the output of my program to it in Java. When I use `WriteLong` then the file does not contain long value. Please explain how I can create this file.
My program is to print prime numbers between `500000` and `10000000`

```
public class primenumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = 5000000;
        long end = 10000000;
        System.out.println("List of prime numbers between " + start + " and " + end);
        for (long i = start; i &lt;= end; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(long i2) {
        if (i2 &lt;= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (long i = 2; i &lt; Math.sqrt(i2); i++) {
            if (i2 % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to write the file?

Comment: Also there are much better ways to find primes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Perhaps the issue is not as much finding primes as it is file io.

Comment: this is code in this i simply test one value but in output file it has aschii values and i want original number which i write

Comment: output contain aschii value but i want original number values import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
 
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(
                "D:\\RandomFile.txt", "rw");

            raf.writeLong(1000000000);

            // Reposition the file pointer to position 0.
            raf.seek(0);

            System.out.println("long: " + raf.readLong());

            raf.close(); }
        catch (IOException ex)
        { System.out.println(ex.toString()); } } }

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want the program to print human readable ASCII long values. You can use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and something like,

```
PrintWriter pw = null;
try {
    pw = new PrintWriter(filePath);
    pw.println("List of prime numbers between " + start + " and " + end);
    for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            pw.println(i);
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    pw.close();
}
```

or, using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filePath)) {
    pw.println("List of prime numbers between " + start + " and " + end);
    for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            pw.println(i);
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you wanted to create a binary file you could use a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Comment: This doesn't actually output to the file, this code still prints to the stdout.

Comment: You are not printing the numbers to file anywhere (it should be pw.println(i). Also use try with resource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html. I tried to edit, but was denied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a PrintWriter, for example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class primenumber {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    long start = 5000000;
    long end = 10000000;
       System.out.println("List of prime numbers between " + start + " and " + end);
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("primes.txt"));

       for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
           if (isPrime(i)) {
               pw.println(i);
           }
       }
       pw.close();
   }

   public static boolean isPrime(long i2) {
       if (i2 <= 1) {
           return false;
       }
       for (long i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(i2); i++) {
           if (i2 % i == 0) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```